# Easiest way to draw tree diagrams?

Tags: c#, javascript, python, graphics

I want to have a program which generates diagrams for trees, ones looking pretty much like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY95V.jpg)

It is to be a part of a project I am working on using C#, but if there is a way to make a Python or Javascript do it, that be okay as well. Maybe some C# library, or JavaScript/Python library with parameters I can provide to it ?

The most important thing, regardless of the programming language, is that it be easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/), which is an interface to the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) .DOT format visualization software. As outlined in the Graphviz [guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf), the .DOT format lets you design graphs similar to the one you posted as well as more much more sophisticated ones.

Here's an example from the `pydot` doc:

```
import pydot
graph = pydot.Dot('graphname', graph_type='digraph') 
subg = pydot.Subgraph('', rank='same') 
subg.add_node(pydot.Node('a')) 
graph.add_subgraph(subg) 
subg.add_node(pydot.Node('b')) 
subg.add_node(pydot.Node('c'))
```

If you're looking at Javascript instead, [canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) is a well-respected library that allows you to draw .DOT graphs to browser canvases.

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up making a simple function to generate the .dot code file after reading the graph and then and letting GraphWiz create the png file by letting the program call it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [C# wrapper around the Graphviz bindings](http://graphviz.codeplex.com/).

I'm working on a project that generates trees with Graphviz (not in C# though) and it works great.